# Optional parameter in query does not work for db2 but works in oracle

Tags: spring-boot, db2

Below query works fine for Oracle database, but for `Db2` it throws error sqlcode -417.

I have looked up similar problems but did not get any definitive answer:

```
@Query(value = "select * from tableName f where (aC is null or f.a_c = aC)", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<tablename> findByFilters(String aC, Pageable pageable);
```

On execution the `error code is -417`

Comment: Can you please provide full stack trace?

Comment: Enable tracing to show the actual SQL sent to Db2 . Arrange for at least one of the parameter-markers has an appropriate CAST, or both them, otherwise Db2 will reject it as invalid SQL.

Comment: WARN 11348 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: -417, SQLState: 42609
ERROR 11348 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-417, SQLSTATE=42609, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.25.13
WARN 11348 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: -516, SQLState: 26501
 ERROR 11348 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-516, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.25.13

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem would be to rewrite the query as the following:

```
select * from tableName f where f.a_c = coalesce(aC, f.a_c)
```

The form of query above is likely to be accepted. In order to find out the exact reason of the error you get, it is necessary to trace the actual SQL statement passed to Db2.

Another option of solving the problem may be to add the CAST operator, which would define the data type of your parameter:

```
select * from tableName f where (cast(aC as integer) is null or f.a_c = aC)
```

This is suggested in the [description of the error you get](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0417n)